# Google Map s not working when using json data

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I'm making a web app. I integrate GMap to know my client position. When I use it with manual number, the code is working. But when I use JSON data, the code is not working. The browser always run and my page can't right click.

This is my code.

[image]

Comment: Why would you post a picture of your code?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should parseInt('value') per lat and lng after separated them from json data